# importing and renaming multiple objects in maya with python

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to import multiple object files in maya using python and use the file name as object name in maya. I have managed to import the objects, but I have only been able to use the file name as a namespace  and not as a object name.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def import_multiple_object_files():
    files_to_import = cmds.fileDialog2(fileFilter =  '*.obj', dialogStyle = 2, caption = 'import multiple object files', fileMode = 4)
    for file_to_import in files_to_import:
        names_list  = file_to_import.split('/')
        object_name = names_list[-1].replace('.obj', '') 
        cmds.file('%s' % file_to_import, i = True, type = "OBJ", namespace = object_name, mergeNamespacesOnClash = False, ignoreVersion = True, options = "mo=0",  loadReferenceDepth  = "all"  )
```

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2eoabgm.png]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your outliner once you ran your script and post it in your question? I think I found a solution for your problem but I'd like to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this script assumes that there is **only one mesh** in your .obj file. In fact, only the first mesh returned from your import is renamed.

To retrieve the returned nodes I used the [returnNewNodes flag](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/file.html#flagreturnNewNodes) from file command.

Then I used the [rename command](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/rename.html) to rename the imported node to your file name.

I also deleted the namespace and mergeNamespacesOnClash flags.

**Note:** I'm a bit lazy today and I hav'nt any .obj files here so I did not test this code. If you want to load an obj file with multiple mesh, give me a comment, I'll edit my answer.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def import_multiple_object_files():
    files_to_import = cmds.fileDialog2(fileFilter =  '*.obj', dialogStyle = 2, caption = 'import multiple object files', fileMode = 4)
    for file_to_import in files_to_import:
        names_list  = file_to_import.split('/')
        object_name = names_list[-1].replace('.obj', '') 
        returnedNodes = cmds.file('%s' % file_to_import, i = True, type = "OBJ", rnn=True, ignoreVersion = True, options = "mo=0",  loadReferenceDepth  = "all"  )
        cmds.rename( returnedNodes[0], object_name)
```